# Why is $\|x_m \| \gt 0\ $?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Prove that any two norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent?

**My Attempt** $:$

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb R^n.$ It's clear that $\|x\| \leq M \|x\|_{\infty}$ where $M = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \|e_i\|,$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th coordinate vector of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is the max norm on $\mathbb R^n.$ Now by the reverse triangle inequality of the norm $\|\cdot \|$ we have $$\left |\|x\| - \|y\| \right | \leq \|x - y\| \leq M \|x - y\|_{\infty}.$$ Therefore the map $N : x \mapsto \|x\|$ is a real valued Lipschitz continuous function on $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the max norm. Since the closed unit sphere $S_{\infty} : = \left \{x \in \mathbb R^n\ \big |\ \|x\|_{\infty} = 1 \right \}$ of $(\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is compact it follows that $N$ attains its minimum on $S_{\infty}.$ Let $x_m \in S_{\infty}$ be such that $N (x) \geq N (x_m) : = m$ for all $x \in S_{\infty}.$ Now for any $x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ we have $\frac {x} {\|x\|_{\infty}} \in S_{\infty}$ and consequently we have  $\left \|\frac {x} {\|x\|_{\infty}} \right \| \geq m$ and hence by homogeneity of the norm $\|\cdot \|$ we have $\|x\| \geq m \|x\|_{\infty}.$ The preceeding inequality continues to hold for $x = 0$ and hence we will be done with the proof if we can somehow show that $m \gt 0.$ Although it's easy to see that $m \geq 0$ I can't quite able to conclude that $m \neq 0.$ Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your kind attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m$ to be zero we would need to have $\|x_m\| = 0$ which by the properties of norms would imply $x_m=0$. But $x_m \in S_\infty$ which doesn't contain $0$.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. How can I overlooked that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of $S_{\infty}$ we could have also taken the closed unit disk and take out an open disk of smaller radius from the middle which is a closed annulus embedded inside closed unit disk and it is also compact being a closed subset of a compact set in a Hausdorff space. Am I right?

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa I think it could work as well.